# java xml validation with relative path to glasshfish config folder

Tags: java, xml, glassfish, relative-path

I searched a lot but couldn't find anything. I want to validate a selected xml file with an schema file. My problem is working relative path is config folder of the Glassfish server.
I tried to get url of the schema file which I copied into same package of the class I run this code but still I can't find the file. I only able to make it work is by copying the file into server config file.

```
URL url = ClassLoader.getSystemResource("/schema.xsd");
File file = new File(url.getPath());
```

But url returns null. How can I find this file and even if I find I believe file object can not be created because my relative path is /home/user/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/config. Any ideas how to solve this problem?
Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The leading slash makes the path absolute. If you remove it, leave just the file name and have that file in the domain/config dir then it should work.

Note that if you'd like this file somewhere else you could also provide a relative path stepping back your directory tree e.g. ../../prj/xsd/schema.xsd

Comment: I dont want to use relative path because it will be kind of static value as it is in domain config file. If server changes or file structure it needed to be done manually. What I wanted is to put that file into project files and tell the server to check inside the project. Can it be found inside a war file?

Comment: In this case you can put your files in the WEB-INF/ dir of your WAR and access it via getServletContext().getRealPath("/WEB-INF/myfile);